# How can I fix these errors in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am a python/django noob and can't get my code to run while trying to learn.  Please let me know how I can fix both the below errors I'm getting, thanks.

In my root folder for my new project, I type this on the command line and this is what happens:

> python manage.py runserver
>
> Validating models...

```
>/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/hashcompat.py:9: DeprecationWarning: django.utils.hashcompat is deprecated; use hashlib instead
  DeprecationWarning)

>Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.core.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x101a00c50>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 92, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 35, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 166, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 72, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 96, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangodblog/models.py", line 40, in <module>
    class ErrorBase(Model):
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangodblog/models.py", line 46, in ErrorBase
    url             = models.URLField(verify_exists=False, null=True, blank=True)
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1277, in __init__
    CharField.__init__(self, verbose_name, name, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 626, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verify_exists''
```

I have looked at my project's code (it's very basic) and don't see any typos.  I'm copying from a book that is 3 years old so I think this is a compatibility issue.

Comment: you seem to pass a kw-argument named verify_exists that isnt declared as a parameter in the function but it's really hard to help without any code.

Comment: The beauty of debugging in Python is that it only sends you one error/exception at a time. This makes it as easy as 123 to know what your problem is. FYI the question is not "How can I fix these errors" it's "how can I fix this error" since there is only one TypeError reported in all that mumbo jumbo (if you were programming in C++ there would be multiple errors reported at once which is a true nightmare).

Comment: Thanks.. turns out my book said to use a deprecated third party app that was calling verify_exits and causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm copying from a book that is 3 years old so I think this is a
>   compatibility issue.

3 years is a very long time.

In django 1.4, the `verify_exists` option was deprecated (this means it was marked for removal), and in 1.5 it was completely removed.

Since 1.5 is the current version, when you install django this is the version that is installed.

As you are going by a book, try to use the same version of django as the book. Otherwise you'll run into a lot more of these issues.

Or, use a more updated reference. Why not try the [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/)?